# passing data to collection that is inside another collection object - oracle

Tags: oracle

I have created a collection to pass the the data and use in procedure:

```
Create or Replace type Search_Type AS Object(
ID Number(38),
SF_ID Varchar(25),
PF_ID Varchar(25),
C_ID SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST
);

Create or Replace Type  Search_Array AS Table of Search_Type;
```

I am invoking the procedure as below:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON  
DECLARE
    v_S_ID     Search_Array;
    v_C_ID     SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
BEGIN
v_S_ID := Search_Array();
v_O_ID := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST();
v_O_ID.Extend(2);
v_O_ID(1) := '4';
v_O_ID(2) := '5';
v_S_ID.EXTEND(4);
v_S_ID(1) := Search_Type(1,'2','3',v_C_ID);

FOR i IN v_S_ID.first..v_S_ID.last LOOP dbms_output.put_line(--'Iteration: '
                                                                          --   || i ||
                                                                             v_S_ID(i).id
                                                                             || ', '
                                                                             || v_S_ID(i).SF_ID
                                                                             || ', '
                                                                             || v_S_ID(i).PF_ID
                                                                             || ', '
                                                                             || v_S_ID(i).C_ID.count);
                END LOOP;

END;
```

I am getting below error:

```
Error report -
ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection
ORA-06512: at line 17
06531. 00000 -  "Reference to uninitialized collection"
*Cause:    An element or member function of a nested table or varray
           was referenced (where an initialized collection is needed)
           without the collection having been initialized.
*Action:   Initialize the collection with an appropriate constructor
           or whole-object assignment.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing few things in your code that I have mentioned as inline comment in the following code:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUT ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2  V_S_ID   SEARCH_ARRAY;
  3  V_C_ID   SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
  4  V_O_ID   SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST; -- added this
  5  BEGIN
  6  V_S_ID      := SEARCH_ARRAY();
  7  V_O_ID      := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST();
  8  V_C_ID      := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST(); -- added this
  9  V_O_ID.EXTEND(2);
 10  V_O_ID(1)   := '4';
 11  V_O_ID(2)   := '5';
 12  V_S_ID.EXTEND(1);  -- CHANGED THIS FROM 4 TO 1
 13  V_S_ID(1)   := SEARCH_TYPE(
 14  1,
 15  '2',
 16  '3',
 17  V_C_ID
 18  );
 19  FOR I IN V_S_ID.FIRST..V_S_ID.LAST LOOP DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(--'Iteration: '
 20                                                                            --   || i ||
 21  V_S_ID(I).ID
 22                                                               || ', '
 23                                                               || V_S_ID(I).SF_ID
 24                                                               || ', '
 25                                                               || V_S_ID(I).PF_ID
 26                                                               || ', '
 27                                                               || V_S_ID(I).C_ID.COUNT);
 28  END LOOP;
 29
 30  END;
 31  /
1, 2, 3, 0

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, inline comment at line 12 helped to solve the problem.